# how do you convert a single column of a 2d array into a ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

How do I turn a single column of an 2d array into an ArrayList?

I have this code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < lordStats[0].length; i++)
        troopList.add (lordStats[i][2]);
//trooplist is a list and lordstats is a 2d array, they are both Strings
```

but it gives me a lot of errors, how do I do this.

These are my errors, all I can figure out is that something in my array is messed up. Note that without these 2 lines of code, the program runs fine.

Line 32-33

```
    for (int i = 0; i < lordStats[0].length; i++)
    troopList.add (lordStats[i][2]);
```

errors:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at arsenalLord.arsenalLordGui(arsenalLord.java:32)
    at arsenalLord.loader(arsenalLord.java:18)
    at siegeText$1.actionPerformed(siegeText.java:41)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6373)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6138)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4735)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2143)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4621)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4282)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4212)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2129)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:679)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:638)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:636)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:652)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:650)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:649)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: Well from the error above, it seems like the code has errors on AWT component. Could you tell or post exactly what is in line 32?

Comment: The array must be initialized, of course. Arrays allow values, but some lists do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to do a loop, you can directly call [Arrays.asList(array[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) method. eg: this should work:

```
 troopList = Arrays.asList(lordStats[2]);
```

where troopList is `List<String>`

Comment: Doesn't this entirely miss the fact that it was the second *column* that the OP wanted in the list?  This gives you the second row, which is obviously much easier.